# How to show console.log() in code in Terminal from web extension firefox?

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

In Web extension Firefox :

- How to show or enable console.log() in my code in the terminal , I used "we-ext run -v" command but it show logs of web extension framework not my logs in my code ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your setup is right? For me, `console.log()` messages are shown in both, [browser console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) and [web console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question. But might help someone since its the top search on google and i was having the same problem.

Just run your extension with:
web-ext run --devtools

A window will pop up with the console for output of background task, etc

Take care.